# Form &lt and &gt query for mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I'm trying to write a node API which will fetch me the product lists according to the filters passed in the API call.

Eg: http://localhost:8080/api/products?price=>100&price=<200&colour=red

I've written below code to fetch all the products.

```
Product.find().populate("images", "image").exec(function(err, products){
    if(err){
        res.status(200);
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            message: err,
        });
    }else{
        res.status(200);
        return res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Products fetched successfully',
            data : products
        });
    }
 });
```

How I should change the above code to work with any filters passed in the API call? I know that if I put `{$and:[{price:{ $gt: 100, $lt: 200 }},{colour:red}]}` for the above example which I've given, I'll get the desired result.

how can form the query Dynamically?

Comment: rename your URL parameters to `minPrice` and `maxPrice` and the rest will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by redefining your query parameters to follow this pattern:

```
api/products?min=100&max=200&colour=red
```

In your router, `req.query` would yield

```
{ min: "100", max: "200", colour: "red" }
```

Use the parameters in your query as:

```
app.get('/api/products', function(req, res) {
    var query = {
        "price": {
            "$gt": parseInt(req.query.min),
            "$lt": parseInt(req.query.max)
        },
        "colour": req.query.colour
    };

    Product.find(query).populate("images", "image").exec(callback);
});
```

---

Generating the query dynamically would depend on a number of factors. Firstly, if the query involves just searching for documents matching on a particular set of fields and those fields are of string type, then all you need is just checking
to see if the req.query object is not empty and use it in your find() query, provided that the parameters exactly match the fields in your schema. For this given scenario, the following example will show the intuition:

**GET**

```
api/products?name=foo&colour=red
```

In your router, req.query would yield

```
{ name: "foo", colour: "red" }
```

which you can then use as your query e.g

```
Product.find({ name: "foo", colour: "red" }).populate(...).exec(callback)
```

**Router**

```
app.get('/api/products', function(req, res) {
    var query = {};
    if (typeof req.query !== 'undefined' && req.query) query = req.query; 

    Product.find(query).populate("images", "image").exec(callback);
});
```

In the event that you have some range queries then you would need to preprocess the query object as in the original answer.

Comment: How to I generate the query dynamically depending on the parameters passed? The parameters passed can differ depending on what filters the user selects. The URL which I gave was only an example of what the parameters can be.

Comment: The `req.query` object generates the query object for you already, you need to preprocess that to suit your conditional needs, like for example the values from the parameters are by default strings so you need to parse them to integer in order for them to work for your query otherwise using the `req.query` object as it is in your query will not yield the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

you should update your query link like:

```
 http://localhost:8080/api/products?minPrice=100&maxPrice=200&colour=red
```

and then generate query in server side like

```
var query = {};
    query = {$and:[
  {price:{ $gte: parseInt(req.query.minPrice)}}, 
  {price: {$lte: parseInt(req.query.maxPrice)}},
  {colour:req.query.colour}]};

Product.find(query).populate("images", "image").exec(function(err, products){ 
  //.....
}
```

**Updated:**

if you passed query in url like above then you can generate query according to passed params.

```
var query = {};
if(req.query.colour) {
  query.colour = req.query.colour
}
if(req.query.quantity) {
  query.quantity= req.query.quantity
}
//... as you need 
// then
Product.find(query).populate("images", "image").exec(function(err, products){ 
   //.....
}
```

Comment: How to I generate the query dynamically depending on the parameters passed? The parameters passed can differ depending on what filters the user selects. The URL which I gave was only an example of what the parameters can be.

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL to

```
http://localhost:8080/api/products?minPrice=100&maxPrice=200&colour=red
```

and your query will be

```
 var query = {
        "price": {
            "$gt": parseInt(req.query.minPrice),
            "$lt": parseInt(req.query.maxPrice)
        },
        "colour": req.query.colour
    };

    Product.find(query, function(err, result) {
    })
```

Comment: How to I generate the query dynamically depending on the parameters passed? The parameters passed can differ depending on what filters the user selects. The URL which I gave was only an example of what the parameters can be.